# Shuffle divs from multiple boxes onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

I got 3 boxes with different content which gets a shuffle onload.

```
<div class="shuffle style">
    <div>A1</div>
    <div>A2</div>
    <div>A3</div>
    <div>A4</div>
    <div>A5</div>
    <div>A6</div>
    <div>A7</div>
    <div>A8</div>
    <div>A9</div>
</div>
<div class="shuffle2 style">
    <div>B1</div>
    <div>B2</div>
    <div>B3</div>
    <div>B4</div>
    <div>B5</div>
    <div>B6</div>
    <div>B7</div>
    <div>B8</div>
    <div>B9</div>
</div>
<div class="shuffle3 style">
    <div>C1</div>
    <div>C2</div>
    <div>C3</div>
    <div>C4</div>
    <div>C5</div>
    <div>C6</div>
    <div>C7</div>
    <div>C8</div>
    <div>C9</div>
</div>
```

i use this code to shuffle:

```
$(function () {
    var parent = $(".shuffle");
    var divs = parent.children().remove();
    while (divs.length) {
        parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
    }
});
```

When all 3 boxes have the same class (.shuffle) the mix is incorrect.
So i added a script for each box with a new class-name (shuffle2, shuffle3).

Is it possible to call this function one script?

See my working Fiddle with 3 scripts [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/oe9wrujm/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```html
<div class="shuffle style">
  <div>A1</div>
  <div>A2</div>
  <div>A3</div>
  <div>A4</div>
</div>
<div class="shuffle style">
  <div>B1</div>
  <div>B2</div>
  <div>B3</div>
  <div>B4</div>
</div>
<div class="shuffle style">
  <div>C1</div>
  <div>C2</div>
  <div>C3</div>
  <div>C4</div>
</div>
```

```js
$(function () {
    $(".shuffle").each(function () {
        var parent = $(this),
            divs = parent.children().remove();

        while (divs.length) {
            parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
        }
    });
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z71zn036/)

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you